# Change color of cancel and done button in CNContactPicker

Tags: ios, swift

```
let cnPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
cnPicker.delegate = self
self.present(cnPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Cancel and Done buttons are white color.

I need to change them to black and couldn't find any info.

How can I do that?

Comment: I accidentally selected swift3 sorry.

Comment: Oh ok I am having a busy day lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do like, change the bar tintcolor and tintcolor of  `UINavigationBar.appearance()` on present

```
let cnPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
 cnPicker.delegate = self
 changeAppearance()
self.present(cnPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

 func changeAppearance() {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .black
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = . black
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:.black]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = .white // customize 
}
```

on dismiss the CNContactPickerViewController again change the appearance

```
 func contactPickerDidCancel(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController) 
{
    resetAppearance()
}

func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact) {
    resetAppearance()
}

func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contactProperty: CNContactProperty) {
    resetAppearance()
}

 func resetAppearance() {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:.black]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = .black // customize 
}
```