# CNContactViewController - change color of cancel and done button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cncontactviewcontroller

When i open `CNContactViewController`, It opens view without cancel and done button. 
This issue only occurs in iOS13 and later.
   [image]

How can i change the bar button colors?

I tried this link,  but it is not working

[Change color of cancel and done button in CNContactPicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50738316/change-color-of-cancel-and-done-button-in-cncontactpicker)

```
let controller = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: nil)
controller.delegate = self
navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked linked is working fine

**change code to**

```
 navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

**with this**

```
 self.present(UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller), animated:true)
```